# Change <input type="text" onkeyup> to <select><option value> onclick (HTML5/js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

title is what it is.
I have this code with input and it works correctly.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="command" onkeyup="command = $(this).val(); command_string();"/>
```

Now I want to do same with select and option value, something like this is:

```
<select id="cmd-id" class="selectpicker form-control" data-dropup-auto="false" data-size="6" name="cmd-id" onclick="this.select();">
        <option value="cmd1">1</option>
        <option value="cmd2">2</option></select>
```

I would like to do this basicly with html, I know it must be possible. I want to get rid of input type'text' and do the same job with selected option value.

**onchange works!**

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="cmd-id" class="selectpicker form-control" data-dropup-auto="false" data-size="6" name="cmd-id" onchange="command = this.value; command_string();">
    <option value="cmd1">1</option>
    <option value="cmd2">2</option>
</select>
```

Replace onclick with onchange.